# How to remove duplicate values from DOM output?

Tags: php, arrays

I have implemented a simple code around HTML DOM script. The output I am receiving has many duplicate values. How to remove these values? I tried array_unique, but it doesn't work. Any pointers?

Below is the code;

```
$path = 'https://www.example.com';

$html = new simple_html_dom();

$url = $html->load_file($path);

if (!empty($url))

$html->load_file($url);
$result = array();
$result1 = array_unique($result);

foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    $href = $a->href;


if (strpos($href, '://')==false) 

{

    $result1[] = $href;

echo $href;
echo'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that you're using `array_unique` too soon. Using array_unique on an empty array will be an empty array, and then you populate the `$result1` afterwards, which won't be unique. (hope that makes sense?)

Comment: Yes. I get that. But I am able to work around the problem. If I use array_unique later, I get error of converting array to string. If I use implode explode function, the string won't remove duplicate results. So I am clueless at the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.
1. You are using `array_unique` too early.
2. You are echo-ing all matches. (While also adding them to an unused array.)

Here's the relevant part of your code, fixed:

```
$result = array();
// THIS WILL ONLY FILTER AN EMPTY ARRAY == DO NOTHING: 
// $result1 = array_unique($result);

foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    $href = $a->href;
    // Assuming you want to match this; then use !== false
    if (strpos($href, '://') !== false) {

        $result[] = $href;

        // If you output, you can't filter for unique values. Ditch this:
        // echo $href;
        // echo'<br />';
    }
}

$result = array_unique($result);

var_dump($result);
```

Then, do whatever you wish with the unique values, including `implode('<br>', $result);` if your desired output is unique links separated by line breaks.